# Where do I store files such as images in a Java project?

Tags: java

I'm trying to access a .jpg file to use as a background like this:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("star_wars.jpg"));;
```

If I change the path to the picture to a directory on my computer that has the file, it works, but I want to give this program out, which means that it will only show up on my PC. I've tried storing it in multiple areas in the project itself, and haven't had any luck. Its currently in a source folder called resources. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it relative to your class file.  In this example, you would put the image file at the same location as your class file.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(MyClass.class.getResource("star_wars.jpg"));
```

Comment: +1 Or relative to the top level of the JAR by adding `/` to the start of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using an engine, there is no `resources` folder, unless you create one yourself.

Relative paths (as yours) are usually relative to the package folder, however in Netbeans, they are relative to the project folder. (Not sure about other IDEs)